# Linking to a static lib that links to a static lib

Tags: .net, c++, .net-2.0

I have a (managed/unmanaged C++) winforms app that links to a static library. That library links to another static library. When I do a Rebuild on the Winforms project, Visual Studio 2005 attempts to rebuild the references static library, but does not rebuild deeper than one level. This causes me to have to manually rebuild the leaf project and then rebuild up the chain to the Winforms project. Is there a way to force a deeper rebuild?

Answer (score 2):

Should I just add all static libs as dependancies to the Winform app?

Comment: This will also work. In fact, I do this because it allows VS to build the dependent libs in parallel, even though they require each other at link time.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Just make sure the n-th level library project is in the same solution, and the immediately dependent library has a dependency on it. VS should rebuild both. This works for native C++ at least, and should work for managed too IFAIK.